# Update All Subscribers Profile Attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio

I want to update an 'all subscribers' custom attribute in the parent bu to match what is in my sending DE in my child unit.

Currently i have a custom attribute in 'all subscribers' called 'contact_type_cd'. I also have a sending DE with a matching column name 'contact_type_cd'. Whatever the value is in my sending DE of my child BU, i want to be updated to the 'all subscribers' level.

For example if my 'subscriber_key' in my sending DE has a value of "dog" in 'contact_type_cd' column i want that same key to reflect the "dog" value in 'all subscribers' if it were to have a value of lets say "animal".

I was hoping the updateDE ampscript function would work, but it doesnt seem to since it is all subscribers or unless my code is wrong.

```
 set @subscriber_key = AttributeValue('subscriber_key')

 set @contact_type_cd = "dog"

 UpdateDE("_subscribers",1,"subscriber_key", @subscriber_key, 
 "contact_type_cd", @contact_type_cd)
```

Is there any other ampscript that i could put in my email that would execute my need at send time? or possibly a simple automation?

Answer (score 1):

_Subscribers is not a DE that you can update. To update a profile attribute I would [recommend an api call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method.htm), which you can do through [ampscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/invokeupdate.htm) if need be or [ssjs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpdate.htm)

```
<soap-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:UpdateRequest>
         <ns1:Options/>
         <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
            <ns1:Attributes>
               <ns1:Name>First Name</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value>Updated</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Attributes>
            <ns1:Attributes>
               <ns1:Name>Last Name</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value>ViaAPI</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Attributes>
            <ns1:SubscriberKey>012345</ns1:SubscriberKey>
            <ns1:Lists>
               <ns1:ID>12345</ns1:ID>
            </ns1:Lists>
            <ns1:Lists>
               <ns1:ID>12346</ns1:ID>
            </ns1:Lists>
         </ns1:Objects>
      </ns1:UpdateRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending an email, marketing cloud is only interested in picking the subscriber key and email address. While sending the email , marketing cloud first lookup at the all subscriber with subscriberkey if found it sends email to the email that is present in all subscriber if not it will create a subscriber with those used in sendable de.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Built-In Subscriber Function in SSJS:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var subscriberProperties = {
    "Attributes":{"contact_type_cd": "dog"}
};

var subObj = Subscriber.Init("your_subscriber_key");
var status = subObj.Update(subscriberProperties);
</script>
```

**Link to docs:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_subscriberUpdate.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).